# German word for towel or a fabric that helps dry baby's skin after bath starts with "Wasch_"

Tags: word-choice, standard-german

I am watching German video on how to bathe a newborn baby, The lady explaining asks for "towel" (the word I am trying to find) to be ready. I looked it up in a few [dictionaries](https://www.dict.cc/?s=towel) but couldn't find the word.

Comment: It would help to include the video with a timestamp, if possible.

Comment: Maybe she's talking about a Waschlappen?

Comment: DWDS lists about 100 compound words involving *Wasch*, and in German you can make up more as needed, so I'm having a hard time seeing how there's enough information given here to answer the question other than to make a guess. I think at least a full sentence for context is needed, or, as infinitezero suggested, a link to the video.

Comment: @AEF: That's it, thank you! You can also post that as an answer so that I can mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @RDBury: I provided context as much as I could. I believe less than half of the compound words you mentioned fit the context.

Comment: A "Waschlappen" (facecloth, washcloth, flannel) is normally a wet cloth used for washing the body, not for drying. You could probably use an adult's "Waschlappen" to help dry a baby, but you would normally user a "Handtuch" (towel). So it's still a bit mysterious.

Comment: @HalvarF: yeah, that's right. It's used for washing the baby, my bad!

Comment: @Gigili: Would you update the question title accordingly? I'm not sure, whether replacing *dry* with *wash* is the desired target.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be **Waschlappen**:
A textile piece for body care. Translation: *washcloth* or *washrag*.

Could be **Waschhandschuh**, a *washing glove/mitt*, the same thing but sometimes called like this because you can put your hand inside the small rectangle shape.

Typically you would use a Waschlappen for cleaning the baby, not drying it, but maybe she considered it as a good alternative because her towels are too big for the baby.

If it wasn't something where you can put your hand inside, but just a small towel, it maybe was a **Seiftuch**, a *soap cloth*, and she simply used the wrong word. A Seiftuch is a small towel typically used for the face, e.g. after shaving or removing make up.

Answer (score -2):

The Word you're searching for is Waschtuch. You can use a "Waschtuch" after you come out the shower i.e

Comment: Is that regional? I've never heard of that before (I'm from the North)

Comment: Das habe ich auch noch nicht gehört. DWDS: "„Waschtuch“ ist nicht in unseren gegenwartssprachlichen lexikalischen Quellen vorhanden. "

Comment: I've never heard this either in Austria, but it sounds Swiss to me. Which is congruent with @LindenKoppejan's bio. (And BTW an important usage note to add to the answer.)

Comment: I never heard that. For me, after a shower you use a Handtuch (albeit for your entire body). A Waschtuch implies something it's being used to wash/clean something, not to dry.

Comment: I concur. Even as a native from southwest Germany, not far from the Swiss border, I never heard the word *Waschtuch*.

Comment: @OliverMason my relatives, which are living near Mannheim us that word. But actually it's the same as Handtuch

Comment: Never heard of it (I'm from southwest) and also Duden doesn't know it.

Comment: A Google search gives 50000 hits for "Waschtuch".

Comment: @Paul Frost: And what does it say once you click on a link? Handtuch, Seiftuch or Waschlappen... There is the word "waschen" and there is "Tuch", so of course you can put those two words together and make up a new word. That's how German works, that doesn't mean the word really exists.

Comment: @Mackie In many links you will excplicitly find the word "Waschtuch". See for example [here](https://www.hygi.de/tork-waschtuch-premium-einzeltuecher-1-karton-8-boxen-x-135-1-080-tuecher-pd-5738). Also see https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=waschtuch. This shows that the word is used and therefore, even if it does not occur in official dictionaries, it **exists**. Many people argued in their comments that they have never heard the  word, but this does not prove non-existence and does not justify downvoting the answer.

Comment: We often had this discussion and it's not really helpful. "Brumwaka" is a word most people likely never heard before, I just made it up, but it now exists. More interesting would be to argue **if** _Waschtuch_ is actually used in the sense of _Handtuch_ (i.e. to dry something) or only to wash/clean something. As stated above, I can imagine what a Waschtuch is, but  I would never guess that it is something to be used **after** a shower.